# react native upload image by post method

Tags: react-native, react-redux, axios, fetch, form-data

i have problem to upload an image to my server my server work with form data and i have other field and i want to send my data by post method but i cant please help me

```
formPoster = () => {
    let body = new FormData();
    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('nationalId', this.state.nationalId);
    formData.append('name',this.state.name);
    formData.append('lastName',this.state.lastName);
    formData.append('mobileNumber',this.state.mobileNumber);
    formData.append('password',this.state.password);
    var fileName = this.state.image.split('/').pop();
    var fileType = this.state.image.split('.').pop();
    var filePath =  'file://' + this.state.image;

    formData.append('file[]', {
      uri: this.state.image,
      name: fileName,
      type: fileType,
 });

 fetch("sample.myserver.......",
  {
    body: formData,
    method: "post"
  });

 }
```

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: there is no error there is just an warning unhandle promise rejection

Comment: and the type of error is network reques failed but when i tried with postman every thing is ok and i know the bug is from react native not the server

Comment: check in network inspector what u are sending to backend

Answer (score 0):

From where you are getting the image, this should be the format

```
let formData = new FormData();
images.map((element: any, index: number) => {
                            const imageUrl: any = {
                                uri: element.uri,
                                type: element.mime,
                                name: `whatever`,
                            };
                            formData.append('imageUrls', imageUrl, `whatever`);
                        });
```

Comment: whats element and the index?

Comment: and what about axios can you tell me a code that work doesn’t matter its fetch or axios just I need to work

Comment: Your this.state.image, you need to post more info to check what is wrong, check what u send in the inspector. And show what is state.image

Answer (score 0):

file type defined is not correct it should be fetched from file.mime

Comment: Can you code that you said because I can’t understand well

Comment: Can you code what you said because I don’t understand well